# inner joining a table with a long key

Tags: mysql

I have 30 character long key between two tables in my database,

The following is an example

CustomerID ::

```
 '004a1dcc-74d4-43ee-ad0f-c142334c86ef'
```

The following is the example of the select statement i have used

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```

The result of the inner join is zero records which is not correct since the number is unique in both tables

Comment: Just out of interest.. why should customers have such a customer id? Imagine they call your customer service and you ask them for their customer id ;)

Comment: This is an example  and not the actual tables in my database

Comment: @B001ᛦ why should a customer have any knowledge about an internal database id?

Comment: @Strawberry what about online shops? And why should we have an internal and another external customer ids?

Comment: A customer might have a username or number. It could (and should) be entirely separate from any internal database id.

Comment: what are the data types of both columns? Do they match?

Comment: in this case customer id is a varchar in both the orders table and customers table @Justin

Comment: varchar 30 I assume? because if one is less then it will truncate and hence no match. Can you also confirm that this Customer ID `'004a1dcc-74d4-43ee-ad0f-c142334c86ef'` exists in both the Customer and Orders table?

Comment: @Justin yes the orders table is set to varchar 80 and customers table is set at varchar  60 ; i have used that example to confirm that my customer Id exist in both tables. I have also tried to convert my customer id into an MD5 with a max of 6 digits but its not unique

Comment: why have you set one table to varchar 80 and the other to varchar 60? These should be identical because they are related fields. Sometimes mysql can be picky and you need to put more information in like the schema name etc.... e.g if your database schema is `dbo`. then it would be `dbo.customers` Other than that - if the data types match and the id is in both tables I can't see why this would not find it

Comment: @B001ᛦ I don't see why customers (or competitors) should have any inkling of the inner workings of a database. Under your system, a competitor can create an account, and get a customer number then they can come back a month later and do the same thing, potentially working out how much new business you're generating; same with orders. Similarly, if you suddenly decide to change the (public) customer numbering scheme (because of exponential growth, for instance), then you have to meticulously update your entire ordering history, as opposed to just updating a bunch of customer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

could be you have some fixed  legnth data type (char ..)  so you could trt using a proepr trim

```
 SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName
 FROM Orders
 INNER JOIN Customers ON trim(Orders.CustomerID ) = trim(Customers.CustomerID);
```

if this is true you could avoid this problem (and the possible   performance degrade based on the use on function) using varchar datatype